# Disable or remove apc

Tags: php, apache, apc, ubuntu-11.04

I installed APC on my ubuntu 11.04 linux and I want to make some performance benchmarks to see what's the speed improvement over PHP without APC but I don't know how to disable/remove the APC.

I tried to empty my apc.ini files but it didn't worked. Still after I load a page for the first time, the page will be stored in the cached and the second time I load the page, it loads much faster.

Here's a PHP file that I use to measure the time.

```
<?php 
    function getTime() 
        { 
        $a = explode (' ',microtime()); 
        return(double) $a[0] + $a[1]; 
        } 
    $Start = getTime(); 
    ?>
    <?php require_once("includes/connection.php");?>
    <?php require_once("includes/functions.php");?>
    <?php
        find_selected_page(true);   
    ?>
    <?php require_once("includes/header.php");?>

        <table id="structure">
            <tr>
                <td id="navigation">
                    <?php echo navigation_public($sel_subject,true);
                      //            $sel_page is sent as a GLOBAL   so that we can reuse is in the page area
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td id="page">
                    <?php

                        if($sel_page!=NULL)
                        {
                            echo "<h2>".htmlentities($sel_page['menu_name'])."</h2>";
                            echo "<p>".strip_tags(nl2br($sel_page['content']),"<b><br><p><a>")."</p>";
                        }
                        else if($sel_subject!=NULL) 
                        {
                            echo "<h2>".$sel_subject['menu_name']."</h2>";
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "<h2>Welcome to Widget Corp</h2>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>   
            </tr>   
        </table>    
        <?php 
    $End = getTime(); 
    echo "Time taken = ".number_format(($End - $Start),3)." secs"; 
    ?>
    <?php require("includes/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Removing the `apc.ini` file should be enough, have you restarted Apache after you cleared that file?

Comment: I removed it's content. Not the file itself. And yes I restarted my apache using the sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart .

Answer (score 11):

Change :

```
extension=apc.so
```

By :

```
;extension=apc.so
```

In :

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/apc.ini
```

And restart Apache server :

```
apache2ctl graceful
```

Comment: Sorry but it seems that the speed of my pages still improves. When I load apc.php in the browser it tells me "No cache info available. APC does not appear to be running." but when I load a page for the first time it takes 0.059 seconds and the second and third time and so on it takes about 0.010 seconds.

Comment: Your methodology for measuring the performance of pages is **wrong**. You are measuring the time PHP takes to run the script - but opcode caches speed up the time taken to **parse** the script - the resulting data structure is the same and processed in the same way. If you want to measure the performance difference, then look at %D in apache log - or use firebug etc.

Comment: @DragosC. you must have another cache activated that's making this performance impovement. (most likely the cache by default in whatever system you are writing your web application).

Answer (score 7):

You can enter the following command with root permission:

```
pecl uninstall apc
```

Answer (score 6):

apc.enabled can be set to 0 to disable APC from php.ini
Than restart your web server or php-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following script then put it on 1st line of your php file,

```
apc_clear_cache();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running apache:

1. edit or create an .htaccess file in the root of your project
2. add this line to the file

   php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off
3. restart the server