# PHP class fatal error call to undefined function stuck globally

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling

In debugging some code I've mistakenly made a call to a member function on a non-object, giving the expected `Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /path/to/file.php on line X`.  I'm accustomed to this, while PHP isn't my favorite language I've been working with it for years.  What's confusing me is that when I remove the offending code (I'm using version control and resetting to what should be a working state prior to the bad call), I still get the error. Is it possible for this error to have corrupted an in-memory (I'm using APC object caching).  I feel like the answer might be "yes, maybe", however I honestly don't think that explains the problem and am wondering if anyone else has encountered something similar?  Is there a method to somehow reset this PHP class object?

Comment: Obvious answer here is to disable APC and see what happens (how-to just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11310236/1301076) ... but doesn't sound likely.

Comment: Do you get the error at the same line in the "working" state? As you are in a dev environment you just have to restart your webserver to clear the apc cache.

Comment: Yeah so I've already disabled APC and restarted the server.  Error persists.  Doesn't make any sense -__-

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but is it the same line in the same file?

Comment: restart the entire stack from the commandline. then go in temp directory and delete the apc cache files. i use hhvm, and occassionally the jit will fail to recompile. i have to restart my stack and delete the hhbc files.